# How to know the referral source of my website/page

Tags: c#, asp.net, search, analytics

I have a website where I want keep track of the Statistics about the users who came to my page from different sources. I want to identify whether user came from Search engines / other websites / direct typing the URL.
 I am using asp.net and C#.
Please help

Comment: I suggest you use some analytics tool like Google analytics for tracking.

Comment: As the posters say below, if all you care about is "where the user came from", then make use of the Referrer HTTP host header.

HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer will give you this functionality.

If you want more than just the referrer, then Google Analytics is the way to go.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Abdel suggests in his comment, the easiest solution would be to use Google Analytics or a similar tool.

If you really want to do this yourself you should look at the [`HttpRequest` type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h55b6cak%28v=VS.100%29.aspx). This is available in your code through the `Page.Request` property. The request has a property for `UrlReferrer` that tells you the url of the page that linked to this one.

Edit: You should be aware that the `UrlReferrer` may not have the information you need. If the user is sent to your page using a Javascript function you may not get a referrer. Also it will be a lot of work to extract really useful information yourself, so the best option is still to use a thrid-party tool like Google Analytics.

Comment: I need to do it myself without third party analytics.
The urlreferrer object always returns me null.

Comment: There are many situations where the UrlReferrer will return null: If the page is opened directly and not from a link, if the page is opened from some types of javascript and maybe flash, if you have browser plug-ins that block this function and some more that I can't remember right now

Answer (score 1):

There is a HTTP header which contains this information: [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer)

Answer (score 0):

Then you'll need to check if the referrer is set in the http header; http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer